# Android timer never executes

Tags: android, timer

I get the current location in my app using `requestLocationUpdates` but in case it takes too long to detect I use a timer to cancel the operation.

For your information I tell you I do all this process in a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` so the device should NOT sleep until either a position is received or the time out happens. Once one of those happens I call to `completeWakefulIntent` to let the device sleep again.

Everything works great but sometimes the timer never finishes and no location is got, either.  I guess my process is maybe killed or destroyed by the system.

So, is there a way to ensure the timer to execute after an amount of time?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Schedule a non repeating alarm once the location finding activity is fired. 
This alarm in turn fires your killer activity that cancels the location finding activity, after an appropriate amount of time

Or use Handler. Something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
     // do something
     // this executes after 2000 milliseconds
   }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Well, yes, but that mess the code with another class and broadcastreceiver and all that. I just need a really simple timer to execute a really simple function

Comment: Will try the Handler idea. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Sorry, same behavior with Handler. It works normally but sometimes (maybe 1 every 10) it never returns a location and it never executes the handler

Answer (score 0):

When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).

Also if this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a `<receiver>` tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning from `onReceive()`. This means you should not perform any operations that return a result to you asynchronously.

Please see the documentation for [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that is why I use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: But WakefulBroadcastReceiver inherits from BroadcastReceiver and have the same restrictions.

Comment: then, there is not a possible solution to asyncronously ensure to do something in a broadcast receive?

Comment: Not that I know of. All examples uses a Service in conjunction with the the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Timer`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //This will execute afteer every 1 Minute
    }
}, 0, 60000);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done already. As I said, timerTask doesn't always execute

Comment: Check my updated answer .... this will be get called after particular interval. its working

Comment: In my case i have to update the UI after certain time... and with this i have done..

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but same results.  It works normally but sometimes (maybe 1 every 10) it never returns a location and it never executes the timer